# Rules of Inference problem of Kenneth Rosen 7e -Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

How to proceed with the question below ?

> For each sets of premises, what relevant conclusion or conclusions can be drawn? Explain the rules of inference used to obtain each conclusion from the premises.
>
> - "If I take the day off, it either rains or snows."
> - "I took Tuesday off or I took Thursday off."
> - "It was sunny on Tuesday."
> - "It did not snow on Thursday."

I proceeded with the question as:

- Let $p$ represent "I take the day off"
- $q$ represent "It rains"
- $r$ represent "It snows"
- $s$ represent "I took Tuesday off"
- $t$ represent "I took Thursday off"
- $u$ represent "It was sunny on Tuesday"
- $v$ represent "It snowed on Thursday"

Then argument form is

1. $p \implies (q \lor r)$
2. $s \lor t$
3. $u$
4. $\neg v$

Now how do I proceed for the conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be assigning propositional variables to the pieces of the sentences; they should be predicates, so that you can substitute the day of the week.

> - "If I take the day off, it either rains or snows."

Let's call this one $$(\forall d)(T (d) \to (R(d) \vee s(d)),$$
where $T(d)$ is "I take take (day) $d$ off", $R(d)$ is "It rains on (day) $d$", and $S(d)$ is "It snows on (day) $d$".

> - "I took Tuesday off or I took Thursday off."

This now becomes $T({\rm Tuesday}) \vee T({\rm Thursday})$.

> - "It was sunny on Tuesday."

This becomes $S({\rm Tuesday})$.

> - "It did not snow on Thursday."

This becomes $\neg s({\rm Thursday})$. Now you can use the rules of inference (including the ones for quantifiers).

(1) $(\forall d)(T (d) \to (R(d) \vee s(d))$ [Assumption]

(2) $T({\rm Tuesday}) \vee T({\rm Thursday})$ [Assumption]

(3) $S({\rm Tuesday})$ [Assumption]

(4) $\neg s({\rm Thursday})$ [Assumption]

We're also missing some key information. It cannot be both rainy and sunny on day $d$, so we have

(5) $(\forall d)(\neg R(d) \vee \neg S(d))$ [Assumption]

Similarly, it cannot be sunny and snow at the same time. Thus

(6) $(\forall d)(\neg s(d) \vee \neg S(d))$ [Assumption]

Now we can use some rules of inference. It was sunny on Tuesday, so we show that it wasn't raining or snowing on Tuesday.

(7) $\neg R({\rm Tuesday}) \vee \neg S({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Universal Instantiation, (5)]

(8) $\neg R({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Disjunctive Syllogism, (7), (3)]

(9) $\neg s({\rm Tuesday}) \vee \neg S({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Universal Instantiation, (6)]

(10) $\neg s({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Disjunctive Syllogism, (9), (3)]

(11) $\neg R({\rm Tuesday}) \wedge \neg s({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Conjunction, (8), (10)]

(12) $\neg (R({\rm Tuesday}) \vee s({\rm Tuesday}))~~~~$ [Logically equivalent to  (11)]

Now we show what days you took off.

(13) $T({\rm Tuesday}) \to (R({\rm Tuesday}) \vee s({\rm Tuesday}))~~~~$ [Universal Instantiation, (1)]

(14) $\neg T({\rm Tuesday})~~~~$ [Modus Tollens, (12), (13)]

(15) $T({\rm Thursday})~~~~$ [Disjunctive Syllogism, (14), (2)]

Now you know you took Thursday off. Now to determine the weather on Thursday.

(16) $T({\rm Thursday}) \to (R({\rm Thursday}) \vee s({\rm Thursday}))~~~~$ [Universal Instantiation, (1)]

(17) $R({\rm Thursday}) \vee s({\rm Thursday})~~~~$ [Modus Ponens, (16), (15)]

(18) $R({\rm Thursday})~~~~$ [Disjunctive Inference, (17), (4)]

Thus it rained on Thursday.

Comment: Thanks for the clear cut explanation @Christopher Carl Heckman

Answer (score 0):

You have $s \lor t$. Assume $s$. If you make the definitions a little more precise, you find that $s \implies p$ and thus $s \implies p \implies (q \lor r)$. We already know that it was sunny on Tuesday, so it was not raining or snowing: $u \implies \neg (q \lor r)$. There we have a contradiction, so our assumption $s$ must be false.

Now it must be $t$. We have $t \implies p \implies (q \lor r)$, but we know it did *not* snow on Thursday as a fact, so $\neg v \implies \neg r$. Therefore $p \implies q$ (not $r$, because that would be a contradiction), and hence the conclusion is that "it rained on Thursday".

Comment: thnx for clear solution, but I have a doubt that we have not used rules of inferences @shardulc

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava We have used them, partly in notation and partly in English.

Comment: Ok. Can we conclude the way you have concluded in an indirect way ?

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava If you want to be absolutely rigorous then the entire reasoning in my answer can be written in appropriate notation.

Comment: ok, thnx, you have helped a lot @shardulc